# Similar to HttpUtility.HtmlDecode for .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity, so I'm stock with .NET 2.0 I want something to function like HttpUtility.HtmlDecode that works for .NET 2.0, how do I do so??

EDIT: My error is: `error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

Comment: I would really suggest to update to a newer version. You are on 10 year old technology. Why not just use a newer version of Unity?

Comment: Use "Microsoft HTML Object Library" (add as reference from com tab) which is a Win32 method that should work with Net 2.0.

Comment: I'm using unity 5 @Patrick Hofman

Comment: So why can't you use a newer version of .NET then?

Comment: not possible in unity, the newest possible version is .NET 2.0 @Patrick Hofman

Comment: Unity even supports Windows Store apps, so they support at least .NET 4.5. I don't know why you think you can't use a higher version of .NET...

Comment: @PatrickHofman No. Unity is 2.0 **some** few 3.5 features. It doesn't support 4 and up but they are working on it.

Comment: According to [this](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.0) they support Windows Store apps. How can they do that without .NET 4? @Programmer

Comment: the builds made by unity are C++, C# is just to control the game's behavior @Patrick Hofman

Comment: [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is present in the .NET 2.0 framework.

Comment: @PatrickHofman They have their own compiler that compiles from C# to C++(IL2CPP) then to other Platform C++ compiler.

Comment: Then why am I getting the error: `error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

Comment: Put `using System.Web;` with your other `using`s.

Comment: I did, and still getting the error

Comment: @user6152883 Have you also added `System.Web` to the references for the project?

Comment: I did before, but when I downloaded it externally it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity did not implement `HttpUtility`.

> I want something to function like HttpUtility.HtmlDecode that works
>   for .NET 2.0, how do I do so??

[Here](https://github.com/Cratesmith/RestSharp-for-unity3d/tree/master/RestSharp/Extensions/MonoHttp) is ported version that works with Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the System.Web.dll file from the internet and added it to my resources folder, then it worked perfectly.

Comment: Test this on a mobile device such as Android and iOS to make sure that it is actually working